# Solution to matrix equation with hadamard product

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

Say I have the following variable length matrix containing unknown values:

$$
AB=\left (\begin{array}{ccc}
ab_{11} & \cdots & ab_{1j}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
ab_{i1} & \cdots & ab_{ij}\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

And the following variable length vectors and matrix (according to the size of the preceding matrix) containing known values:

$$
A=\left (\begin{array}{c}
a_1 \\
\vdots\\
a_n\\
\end{array}\right)
B=\left (\begin{array}{c}
b_1 \\
\vdots\\
b_m\\
\end{array}\right)
K=\left (\begin{array}{ccc}
k_{11} & \cdots & k_{1m} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k_{n1} & \cdots & k_{nm}\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

These are all related by the following equation:
$$
AB = [A \cdot B^T - A \cdot 1_n^T \cdot AB - AB \cdot 1_m \cdot B^T + AB \cdot 1_m \cdot1_n^T \cdot AB]\circ K\\
$$

Where $1_i$ is a column vector of length $i$ containing all $1$'s. Given all of the known values, I want to know if it is possible to solve for $AB$. If so how should I go about figuring this out? I only have a basic education on matrix math.

Comment: Let's use $c_{ij} = ab_{ij}$ to avoid notation conflict. It looks like your matrix equation could be expressed as $$ c_{ij} = k_{ij}\left(a_i-\sum_{k=1}^m c_{ik}\right)\left( b_j - \sum_{k=1}^n c_{kj} \right) ,$$ some kind of simultaneous quadratic  equations.

Comment: Yes I can put it in the form of simultaneous qudratic equations. I am looking for a way to solve this analytically, and I am hoping there could be some matrix methods to do this, but I am begining to think there may not be.